# How can I hash a password in Tornado with minimal blocking?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, bcrypt, pbkdf2

I'm using [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), but this applies equally to BCrypt.

Hashing a password with a reasonable number of iterations can easily block for 0.5 seconds. What is a lightweight way to take this out of process? I'm reluctant to setup something like Celery or Gearman just for this operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a thread. This will not block tornado. Say that you have a handler that hashes passwords. Then the two relevant methods might look like this:

```
import threading

def on_message(self, message):
    # pull out user and password from message somehow
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.hash_password, args=(user, password))
    thread.start()


def hash_password(self, user, password):
    # do the hash and save to db or check against hashed password
```

You could either wait for the thread to finish in the `on_message` method then write the response, or if you don't need to send a response then just let it finish and save the results in the `hash_password` method.

If you do wait for the thread to finish you have to be careful how you do it. `time.sleep` will block so you will want to use tornado's non blocking wait instead.

Comment: Hmm, looks like I can add a callback to the IOLoop from the thread and it works. Thanks.