# How to convert a synchronous function to an asynchronous function in python using callbacks?

Tags: python, mongodb, asynchronous, tornado, synchronous

I'm using the tornado framework and all of my functions have been written synchronously. How would I make these async?

```
class AuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):

        self.render("login.html")

    def post(self):
        username = self.get_argument("UserName",strip = True)
        password = self.get_argument("Password",strip = True)
        user = auth_actions.login(username,password)
        if not user:
            self.redirect("/auth/login")
            return

        #user = user_actions.get_my_data(self.db,user['_id'])

        self.set_secure_cookie("userdata", tornado.escape.json_encode(dumps(user.to_mongo())))
        self.redirect("/")


def login(username,password,callback=None):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(password)
    hashed = m.hexdigest()
    login = User.objects(UserName=username.lower(),Password=hashed).exclude("Password","Wall","FriendsRequested","Friends","FriendsRequesting")
    if login.first() is None:
        login = User.objects(Email=username.lower(),Password=hashed).exclude("Password","Wall","FriendsRequested","Friends","FriendsRequesting")
        if login.first() is None:
            return None
    logger.info(username + " has logged in")
    if callback != None:
        return callback(login.first())

    return login.first()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As andy boot mentions, you are going to need a separate thread. The code below uses the `generator`-`coroutine` approach from [tornado-gen](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#module-tornado.gen).
Also note the `run_async` `decorator` that wraps your function up in its own thread.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
import time
from threading import Thread
from functools import wraps

def run_async(func):
  @wraps(func)
  def async_func(*args, **kwargs):
    func_hl = Thread(target = func, args = args, kwargs = kwargs)
    func_hl.start()
    return func_hl

  return async_func

@run_async
def login(username,password,callback=None):
  m = hashlib.md5()
  m.update(password)
  hashed = m.hexdigest()
  login = User.objects(UserName=username.lower(),Password=hashed).exclude("Password","Wall","FriendsRequested","Friends","FriendsRequesting")
  if login.first() is None:
    login = User.objects(Email=username.lower(),Password=hashed).exclude("Password","Wall","FriendsRequested","Friends","FriendsRequesting")
    if login.first() is None:
      return None
  logger.info(username + " has logged in")
  if callback != None:
    return callback(login.first())
  return login.first()


class AuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler):
  @tornado.web.asynchronous
  def get(self):
    self.render("login.html")

  @tornado.web.asynchronous
  @tornado.gen.coroutine
  def post(self):
    username = self.get_argument("UserName",strip = True)
    password = self.get_argument("Password",strip = True)
    user = yield tornado.gen.Task(auth_actions.login, username, password)
    if not user:
      self.redirect("/auth/login")
      return
    self.set_secure_cookie("userdata", tornado.escape.json_encode(dumps(user.to_mongo())))
    self.redirect("/")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be hashing passwords you are best of doing it in a separate thread. This is because a hash takes a long time to execute and will block the main thread.

[Here is an example of hashing on a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103049/how-can-i-hash-a-password-in-tornado-with-minimal-blocking)

Note that Tornado's maintainer Ben Darnell recommends using a separate thread to do password hashes: [see this google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/wQgm_Slh5II).